# Puzzling Type Mismatch in Scala foldRight

Tags: scala, type-mismatch

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this function definition?

```
def incr[Int](l: List[Int]): List[Int] = 
  l.foldRight(List[Int]())((x,z) => (x+1) :: z)
```

Scala compiler is complaining about type mismatch in the body of the function passed to `foldRight`:

```
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
           l.foldRight(List[Int]())((x,z) => (x+1) :: z)
                                                ^
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 7):

With `def incr[Int]` you've defined an arbitrary type with the name `Int`, which overrides the existing one. Get rid of the `[Int]` type parameter and it works fine, or use a different name like `T`.

Comment: Same error with this:     `def incr[T](l: List[T]): List[T] = l.foldRight(List[T]())((x,z) => (x+1) :: z)`   still don't understand (?)

Comment: Sorry to be so dense, stupid, got it.  Thanks. `def incr(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = l.foldRight(List[Int]())((x,z) => (x+1) :: z)`

Comment: @Bill an arbitrary type doesn't have a `+` method, which is why either your element type needs to be `Int` or the function you pass to foldRight needs to work on `Any`. I'm not exactly sure why this exact error message is produced but it's probably something to do with the compiler thinking `+` is the method for concatenating Strings. It would be nice if the compiler gave you a warning though about shadowing types.

Comment: Yeah - I was working through the exercises in a book (Functional Programming in Scala) that I just bought and became so used to introducing type parameters that I became blinded for the moment. I realized my error as soon as I shutdown for the evening. A relaxed mind thinks so much more clearly...  :-)

Answer (score 2):

What Luigi says works for me. I'm not sure why you would want the type parameter since you're already specifying the input as a List of Int:

```
def incr(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = l.foldRight(List[Int]())((x,z) => (x+1) :: z)

incr(List(1,2,3))                 //> res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```

But on a sidenote and not related to the actual question, if that's the intended outcome, an alternative way could be:

```
def incr2(l:List[Int]):List[Int] = l map (_+1)
```